# Why descend after a single engine failure in an Airbus?

Tags: airbus-a320, airbus, emergency-procedures, engine-failure

The procedure says to descend to lrc ceiling. But, why do we need to descend?

The aircraft is still able to maintain speed even at higher altitudes,
at FL300, in FS2020, it was maintaining around 215-225 knots speed with N1 around 89 percent.
When I descended to FL150, though it is able to maintain 300 knots, power is still around same.

So why descend?

Comment: What do the real world performance charts say? Maybe the A320 in the flight simulator does not have accurate performance (especially in non-normal situations).

Comment: An Airbus can not maintain FL300 on one engine. Your simulation might be flawed, but my guess is you didn’t wait long enough for the airspeed to decrease. If you did, you would probably find the max altitude on one engine would be about FL200.

Comment: You descend to an altitude, which will be well below FL300, based on the best performance available for one engine inoperative operation. This altitude varies somewhat based on weight, temp, etc.

Comment: Beyond the fact that FS2020 is not a suitable mean of testing real aircraft performance. As you have written: "to lrc" i.e. Long Range Cruise. The docs don't imply that the aircraft isn't able to maintain FL300, but that descending will improve the range which is useful in case of one engine failure.

Comment: What I really want to know is that why we need to descend... I tired it in fenix and it seems to be holding speed... people told that the aircraft may not be able to maintain speed but thats not the case and as i think the simulation is right

Comment: so it will be nice if someone can give a correct and accurate explanation of real reason required to descend,.. thanks much

Comment: If you are flying ETOPS and over the middle of the pacific ocean you will need (and your flight planning requirements demand) that you descend to an altitude that will provide the best range/fuel performance (which would be well below FL300).  If you are flying over the Himalayas and need to remain above a particular altitude for a while you would "drift down" to an altitude which will allow (hopefully) terrain clearance.  So, the performance requirements after an engine failure depend on what circumstance you find yourself in.  It's not all about staying as high as possible.

Comment: @quietflyer  Fortunately, in modern aircraft (1980's and later) your FMC (or similar) will display your engine inop best range altitude based on the circumstances (weight, temp, etc.) at the time of the engine failure.

Comment: @757toga -- my thought was more in terms of a slower descent rate versus a faster descent rate-- ( re "So maybe now we need another question about what is the most efficient *way* to descend to the altitude that will provide the best single-engine range?")

Comment: @quietflyer. Why don't you ask that question.

Comment: @757toga you went into the other strategies, but here i'm asking for a standard situation where there is no mountains/etops... simply what is the advantage for that situation.. be particular pls thanks...

Comment: from your answer it seems it's done only to increase endurance, is it ?

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: FenixSim is WRONG. A real Airbus A320 can NOT maintain FL300 on one engine. That is the reason for the descent.

Comment: @quietflyer the most efficient single engine descent is included in QRH performance data and is called "driftdown" speed. Driftdown is basically max L/D with one engine inop and the other at max cont thrust.

Answer (score 4):

Your simulation is almost certainly flawed. For example, an Airbus A320 that loses an engine at Fl330 must descend. There is the single-engine ceiling at which a plane can **maintain** speed and altitude efficiently. If you want to maintain altitude, then you must sacrifice speed. If you want to maintain speed, then you must sacrifice altitude. If you want to do both simultaneously, descend.

Summarised from here: [Mentour Pilot's video on this topic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v-Wp28oNZDE)